# How can I update the value of the first element that meets a criteria across a specific dimension for a 3D tensor?

Tags: pytorch

I have a 3D tensor. For the first element in the 2nd dimension that meets the criteria (`val==1`), I want to update the value to 2). Each vector across the 2nd dimension will always start with a 0 and end with at least one 1.

**Example Input:**

```
x = torch.tensor([[[   0, 2239, 6255,    1,    1],
         [   0,    1,    1,    1,    1],
         [   0,    1,    1,    1,    1]],

        [[   0, 7596, 2027, 2007,    1],
         [   0, 2030, 6255, 2752,    1],
         [   0,    1,    1,    1,    1]],

        [[   0, 2027, 2007, 2030,    1],
         [   0, 2064, 6255, 2012,    1],
         [   0, 2007, 2940,    1,    1]],

        [[   0, 2027, 2007, 2030,    1],
         [   0, 2064, 6255, 2012,    1],
         [   0, 2007, 2940, 2940,    1]]])
```

**Desired Output:**

```
tensor([[[   0, 2239, 6255,    2,    1],
         [   0,    2,    1,    1,    1],
         [   0,    2,    1,    1,    1]],

        [[   0, 7596, 2027, 2007,    2],
         [   0, 2030, 6255, 2752,    2],
         [   0,    2,    1,    1,    1]],

        [[   0, 2027, 2007, 2030,    2],
         [   0, 2064, 6255, 2012,    2],
         [   0, 2007, 2940,    2,    1]],

        [[   0, 2027, 2007, 2030,    2],
         [   0, 2064, 6255, 2012,    2],
         [   0, 2007, 2940, 2940,    2]]])
```

So far I tried finding all the indexes where the element is equal to 1, but I'm struggling to filter for the first index across the second dimension.

```py
ids = torch.argwhere(x==1)

# TODO: code to filter ids to the first match across dimensions 2

x[ids[:, 0], ids[:, 1], ids[:, 2]] = 2
```

How can I do this in pytorch?

Comment: `torch.scatter(x, 2, (x == 1).mul(1).argmax(2, True), 2)`